# Compare ndarray item with lower case string

Tags: python

I have this block of code:

```
vals = df.values
col1 = vals[:, 0]
#np.char.lower(col1)
header_start = (col1 == 'name').argmax()
eodf = (col1 == 'pass through').argmax()
```

col1:

```
['test sample' 'section' 'Name' 'Mike' 'Nancy' 'Bob' 'Terrance' 'Sara'
 'Myo' 'Pass Through']
```

I essentially want this to ID the first and last row location and store it into `header_start` and `eodf`. I also want to accommodate typos and compare everything in lower case. I can't figure out how to apply lower to the col1 item. Any ideas?

When I try to run that commented line, I get this error: `string operation on non-string array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new array with lower case

```
import numpy as np
col1 = ['test sample', 'section', 'Name', 'Mike', 'Nancy', 'Bob', 'Terrance', 'Sara', 'Myo', 'Pass Through']
new_col1 = np.asarray([i.lower() for i in col1])

header_start = (new_col1 == 'name').argmax()
eodf = (new_col1 == 'pass through').argmax()

print(header_start)
print(eodf)
```

Or you don't want to create new, just replace `col1` array

```
import numpy as np
col1 = ['test sample', 'section', 'Name', 'Mike', 'Nancy', 'Bob', 'Terrance', 'Sara', 'Myo', 'Pass Through']
col1 = np.asarray([i.lower() for i in col1])

header_start = (col1 == 'name').argmax()
eodf = (col1 == 'pass through').argmax()

print(header_start)
print(eodf)
```

Result:

```
2
9
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the commented line with this:

```
for index, i in enumerate(col1):
    col1[index] = i.lower()
```

It makes each item in the list lowercase.